NodeJS file preview followed by Download throws network error
I need to preview PDF first and then followed by download. I do not want user to download first and then preview,
SO here is what I did:
var data =fs.readFileSync('/demo.pdf');
res.contentType("application/pdf");
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=ank.pdf');
res.send(data);

in localhost, it is working like charm, successfully previewed in Chrome, and then click the download icon in browser, user can download the file immediately,
But after we deployed to cloud, this is broken, we can preview in browser, but when click  the browser download icon, we saw the connection error in the download dropdown in the top right of the browser, "File wasn't available on Site" or "check internet connection"
I checked the browser network,
in local, there is one header 'Connection: keep-alive' , but in our cloud, there is no more header like this, don't know if this is the cause.
I changed the inline to attachment, it worked, but that is not what we need.
This only broke in Chrome, worked in FF and Safari
Hope to hear your advice, thanks

can't reproduce. maybe try inspecting caching headers... see also: chrome PDF viewer can't download file and "Network failure" to download PDF generated with with PHP FPDF/FPDF2File class in Google Chrome
